# Deserializing with generics using Micronaut Serialization without using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, micronaut, suppress-warnings, micronaut-serde

I try to deserialize a generic Object `W<T>` from JSON with [Micronaut Serialization](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization) , it works, but the compiler produces an "unchecked assignment" warning.

I would like to achieve the same result without the warning or using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

The following is a reduced version of the code I use. It works, but there is a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

1st note: The `ObjectMapper` is not the Jackson ObjectMapper, but the `io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper`
2nd note: I removed common `java` and `slf4j` imports for brevity

```java
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Prototype;
import io.micronaut.core.type.Argument;
import io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@Prototype
public class Scratch {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public Scratch(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Optional<CommonResponse<JobResponse>> getCommonResponse(final String entry) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(objectMapper.readValue(entry, Argument.of(CommonResponse.class, JobResponse.class)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("Could not deserialize, skipping entry: '{}'", entry, e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with `Argument.of`, but there is `GenericArgument` which is exactly what is needed.

Full example:

```java
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Prototype;
import io.micronaut.core.type.GenericArgument;
import io.micronaut.serde.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@Prototype
public class Scratch {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public Scratch(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    private Optional<CommonResponse<JobResponse>> getCommonResponse(final String entry) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(objectMapper.readValue(entry, new GenericArgument<>() {}));
        } catch (IOException e) {
           LOG.warn("Could not deserialize, skipping entry: '{}'", entry, e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/2204